# I have created a console command but unable to run it on the console in Symfony 4

Tags: symfony

I have created a app and have created a CreateLessonFromScheduleCommand.php and trying to run it on console using

php bin/console app:create-lesson-from-schedule

It is giving error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMUsh.png)

but it is not going inside it

My file Path is i have a C:\xampp\htdocs\app\src\Command\CreateLessonFromScheduleCommand.php

Please let me know how to run this file in  console so that i can move further in it.

Thanking You

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: Please share the code of your command. And check that it's registered: https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/console.html#registering-the-command

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is running code and and only i have to solve the issue in it of time difference and that why i m trying to run but it on console as it is executed using cron after some time and i want to run it on the console to debug the issue
The error is as